# Spring jms listener thread died on an exception

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

I am not sure if this has been asked earlier but i am using DefaultMessageListenerContainer with concurrency set to 1 ( default value i believe , i have not supplied anything in `<listener-container>` and `<listener>` element).
I get an exception like below in listener thread so i believe spring jms automatically recovers it and resumes normal consumption of message ( I have seen this behavior for some of my apps).

But in one case , i dont see it being recovered and am trying to debug the possible reasons for same.
Can someone please assist or give some hint/clue ?

Exception received in listener thread ( Listener method has return type of String which is sent to producer of the message and this exception occurred during sending of this String response) :-

```
javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Queue: TempQueueef6a4d33-73d0-48de-b235-7a2b10d21bac is not a valid destination
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Which broker implementation are you using? ActiveMQ or something else? Can you also copy your application context please and also the listener code?

Comment: I am using Apache Qpid.I dont have exact applicationContext right now , it is somewhat similar to below

Comment: <listener-container> <listner id="", ref="" , method=""> </listener></listener-container>  ................ Also the ref is implementing sessionAware interface.

Comment: Just an update on this , after doing some analysis , i found that Spring JMS is creating new queue consumer with Qpid broker without closing the previous queue consumer.And this seems to be the root cause of the issue.Any pointers on this ?